# how to in excel with formula filter range input containg text and number

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, numbers, array-formulas

I need your help, after many tries and searches here I couldn't yet reach my goal.

This is excel-formula doubt.

My `A1` from sheet `Tags` contains the following values as example:

```
adm  
as  
ad  
b02  
b02_e11  
b02_e14  
b807-10_e3  
b807-10_e4  
b807_e1  
batch  
bp  
... and many more entries.
```

with the following formula I was able to collect only matching values starting with `b`:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Tags!$A$1:$A$999,SMALL(IF(LEFT(Tags!$A$1:$A$999,1)=$A$7,ROW(Tags!$A$1:$A$999)),ROW(1:1)),1),"")}
```

`A7` from `Summary` sheet contains the character `b`.

the result of the above formula returns to me the following sequence:

```
b02  
b02_e11  
b02_e14  
b807-10_e3  
b807-10_e4  
b807_e1  
batch  
bp
```

But I don't want to have in the sequence the values `batch` or `bp` or any other value that starts with b and do not have an number after, I'm just want values like `b0`, `b1`, ... , `b8`.

To reach my goal I have tried many workarounds like adding the following formula and an array inside:

```
=COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1))>0
```

Between my current IF statement:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Tags!$A$1:$A$999,SMALL(IF(AND(LEFT(Tags!$A$1:$A$999,1)=$A$7,COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},B2))>0),ROW(Tags!$A$1:$A$999)),ROW(1:1)),1),"")}
```

*`B2`is where I suppose to paste the formula since `B1` contains the header.

The above formula returns many 0's to me.

I hope I could give you enough information and sorry if I couldn't be more precisely I'm not yet able to paste images here.

Thank you,
Rodrigo

Comment: `...SMALL(IF((LEFT(Tags!$A$1:$A$999,1)=$A$7)*(ISNUMBER(--MID(Tags!$A$1:$A$999,2,1))),...`

Answer (score 1):

I find that AGGREGATE makes it easier to add additional conditions.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(tags!A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$999)/((LEFT(tags!A$1:A$999, 1)=$C$3)*(ISNUMBER(--MID(tags!A$1:A$999, 2, 1)))), ROW(1:1))), TEXT(,))
```

I've also reduced some redundant characters and minimized cell range references.

Comment: Hi Jeeped thank you for answer, I will try it and report back if that worked for me or not.